# Flatten a multi dimensional array inside a multi dimensional array but retain keys?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, multidimensional-array

```
$arr = [
    'name' => 'John',
    'access' => '1',
    'address' => [
        'line_1' => '10',
        'line_2' => 'example street',
    ],
]
```

How can I flatten this example array (or turn it into a collection) without losing keys, I've tried  to use collect and flatten but this loses the keys.

I'm expecting this:

```
$arr = [
    'name' => 'John',
    'access' => '1',
    'line_1' => '10',
    'line_2' => 'example street',
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this by using core iterator functions,

```
$temp = [];
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
foreach($it as $k => $v) {
  $temp[$k] = $v;
}
print_r($temp);
```

[RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) - Can be used to iterate through recursive iterators.

[RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) - This iterator allows to unset and modify values and keys while iterating over Arrays and Objects in the same way as the [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php). Additionally it is possible to iterate over the current iterator entry.

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [name] => John
    [access] => 1
    [line_1] => 10
    [line_2] => example street
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f327bde4550122cc4d9dfb0a3c44b80e16aa387e).

Comment: I don't currently have this problem but Very nice, idk why i don't know this but usually i do the recursivity func manually, but this is satisfying, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think @Rahul Meshram's solution is better, but you can try this one, too.

[Try](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/75038742eed4baf23f1920b4bad91465526fcb63)

```
    <?php

$arr = [
    'name' => 'John',
    'access' => '1',
    'address' => [
        'line_1' => '10',
        'line_2' => 'example street',
    ],
];

$newArray = [];

foreach ($arr as $k1 => $v1){

    if(is_array($v1) && count($v1) > 0){
        foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2){
            $newArray[$k2] = $v2 ;
        }
    }else {
        $newArray[$k1] = $v1 ;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```